# Wrong display of radDatePicker telerik under ie

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Under only IE my radDatePicker looks like this:

[image]

The code is:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker TabIndex="17" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Default" ...
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, solve it as follows:

I put a RadDatePicker with css

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker3" runat="server" CssClass="RadInput_HIDE">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

the css was

```
.RadInput_HIDE  
{    
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options (things we do in that not so rare case).

1. Check if your html renders differently in standard and in compatibility mode (check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx)). If it renders correctly in standard mode and just not in compatibility mode, add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"> to the header and see if this works (only IE > 7, I believe) or [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks) - forcing the page to render in standard mode may or may not be an option.
2. Consider using [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) - it helps with all kinds of cross browser compatibility issues (but may require some work to implement).
3. If the two above won't help, target the Telerik-generated CSS directly by looking into the html source and limit the patches to the IE version that needs it by implementing any suitable [IE hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213309/in-line-css-ie-hack).
4. We've had so many issues with the Telerik DatePicker that we quit using it - that may be an option as well. We prefer [jQuery datepickers](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) now.